# InDesign plugin with Boost.Filesystem doesn't show up in the program

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems, adobe-indesign

I try to develop custom InDesign plugin using Adobe SDK. Everything was fine until I added some functionality from Boost.Filesystem. When I statically link `boost_filesystem` and `boost_system` to the solution everything builds and plugin is compiled, but InDesign does not load it. After removing them, it shows up in InDesign again. Does anyone know why does it happen and how to solve this issue?

Comment: What OS are you on? What have you done to debug the problem? Is anything written to a console log? How do you know the plug-in isn't being loaded? Could it be getting loaded, but somehow telling the app it can't perform a function? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try checking dependencies of your plugin using DUMPBIN /DEPENDENTS , you might find out that the dll has been accidently linked dynamicaly with some library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checking the boost build command is maybe usefull

boost can be build with static link to c runtime or dynamic link to c runtime

i think you should static link to c runtime
bjam --with-filesystem --with-sytem **runtime-link=static** link=static

Comment: That was actually this problem, but I still cannot tell why. Could you explain further?

Comment: first, your program should link to C runtime, then, when you dynamic link to C runtime, the C runtime DLL must be depolyed to target computer, if the C runtime don't be depolyed, the program will not run, you can see the "Event Log" for that. so, just static link to C runtime, your app will has nothing dependents,  it should run OK.  by the way, static link will increase the binary size.

Answer (score 0):

You should include your boost lib from InDesign executable :
You can find them on mac in /Adobe InDesign CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks